# PHP, CentOS 6.5 - how to make the time accurate?

Tags: php, centos6

I have CentOS and its set to Belgium time.

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
# php --version
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Oct 30 2014 20:12:53) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
# ntpdate be.pool.ntp.org
```

Now i have user coming to that site from:

```
United States
United Kingdom
Japan
Australia
UAE
```

When they open my page, they all see wrong time (shows Belgium time)

test.php:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

How can i show them `ntpdate be.pool.ntp.org` like accurate exact time of there country zone, also automatically tune it when time changes 1hour +/- (instead showing default server time)?

Comment: You'll need to be able to determine the timezone they are in before you can modify the timezone in PHP. Do you have a way of determining that?

Comment: I can know from the visitor point of view that he is coming from: United States or United Kingdom or United arab amirat or Japan or Australia. (i have that detector)

Comment: The simplest answer is to use [DateTime objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

Comment: Like this? `$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Belgium'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:P') . "\n";` ?

Comment: I know the person Country name only. How can i put it in DateTime Object?

Answer (score 1):

The best way around it is for the application to work in UTC. If you are storing any dates, store them in UTC as well. This will allow you to calculate local time from user time zone using JavaScript. You can use a library like moment.js to do this for you:

http://momentjs.com/timezone/

If you are just displaying the current time use just JavaScript.

```
<script>
    var date = new Date();
    document.getElementById("date-time").innerHTML = date.toDateString();
</script>
```

That is the simplest solution to the problem as PHP is not aware of client's timezone, while JavaScript is as it's executed in the browser.